# Delete rows with parent/child relation in single table from stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, parent-child, circular-reference

I need to suggestion how can be resolve this problem.

Table is constructed with parent/child relations columns and contains foreign key between this relations.

| Id | ParentId |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | NULL |

In my stored procedure I added deleting all children in first query and then deleting all parent. All children delete correctly but during parents rows deleting throw error:

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the SAME TABLE REFERENCE constraint.

Findings:

1. Set foreign key with 'ON DELETED CASCADE' will throw exception:

   > may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths
2. Execute below queries in stored procedure will throw exception:

   > The DELETE statement conflicted with the SAME TABLE REFERENCE constraint
3. Inconsistent data in table causes that cannot recreate foreign key
4. I tried to wrap delete query with EXEC inside stored procedure, although it throw same exception like from point 2

How could be this problem resolve without deleting constraint from table or separating executions this queries into different stored procedure?

Comment: Without cascading, you'll need to use recursion to get the to lowest child row first, and delete each set in reverse. If you used a true `hierarchyid` then you could just delete the entire tree quite easily. Though, if you have circular references, as you state, that is going to pose problem as well.

Comment: I thought also about set cascading deletion but it's by default disable in mssql when recognize circular references. During set foregin key with cascading, it throw error: "may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths"

Comment: @Larnu I believe you can delete the whole set in one go using a recursive CTE (you need to rejoin because rCTE is not updatable) https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=260f8a0a0290a97ccbd9fefa94bd5a32

Comment: @Charlieface I tested your solutions and it works with CTE, although it's turned out that also need to be set nocheck on foreign key

Comment: Interesting, I can do it with constraints enabled https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9a7c15e134c73f22c3c940f17b2d3c20

Comment: Yes, it's right I also during test can do it with enabled, it's seems that is sth with env or db version. I will come back with answer why is required after taking answer from my architect

Answer (score 4):

**You can delete a row with all its descendant rows using a recursive CTE**

We need to add a `topParent` check due to cycles, but so long as all rows are deleted there should be no foreign key error

```sql
with cte as (
    select id, id as topParent
      from YourTable t
      where t.id = @parentId
    union all
    select t.id, cte.topParent
      from YourTable t
      join cte on cte.id = t.parent
      where cte.topParent <> t.id
)
delete from t
from YourTable t
join cte on cte.id = t.id;
```

[db<>fiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=30608755123e09635cb06041212a16a6)

Answer (score -2):

if you set the forgein key as Cascade for delete you do not need to delete related records on child table . just delete on parent table record on the child table will delete automatically . It seems deleting records manually may cause the problem

Comment: You're rights but this options cannot be set within this kind on relations. When I try to use it I got exception: "may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths"

Comment: I thinks you have recursive relation between tables . To check it please send me the create script of tables

Answer (score -2):

To be clear, the best approach to design a hierarchy is not the nested set method (an auto foreign key on the table), but it is the "interval" method, and then, with this method, the deletion of all a hierarchy with all the child and subchild will be done by a simple WHERE predicate.

Comment: [Your answer is in another castle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/397219)

Comment: While this is mostly links, there is still a substantial amount of content for this to be somewhat valuable. I don't think you can classify this as a link-only answer.

Comment: I’d review your terms. I believe what you’re referring to as the “‘interval’ method” _is_ the nested set method, and what you’re referring to as the nested set method is actually an adjacency list.

Comment: Yes, excuse me for the confusion !

Comment: At best, therefore, the links are noise @ConnorLow . Links should compliment an answer, such as citing a resource or linking an article that provides good addition reading on a well informed answer, but should not be the majority of the content. If the links die, does the answer here still have value? Possibly. As, however, all the articles aren't in English this means that they hold little value for this specific site, which is an English community; I would therefore say they should all be removed as noise. At worst, this answer comes across as self promotion in of the users off site content.

Comment: This answer is [being discussed on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/410515/6296561).

Comment: If you have indeed confused the terms, you should edit the answer appropriately. Also, this answer would be substantially improved by providing some sample data and showing the precise SQL statement needed for the deletion. In addition, it's [not always the "best" approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model#Drawbacks).